# Wordpress built in functions cant be recognize on ajax php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im new on Wordpress developing and I having hard time with the ajax on wordpress.

I am trying to build a plugin that is using an ajax. My php file `(xxxecommerce.ajax.php)` doest recognize the built in functions on wordpress like `get_option('xxx-ecommerce-admin2-email');` and I cant even extend to WP_Widget (Honestly Im not sure if I need to extend, i just tried to)

This is how i include the files.

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'xxxecommerce1',
    plugins_url( '/script.js', __FILE__ ),
    array( 'jquery' )
);

wp_localize_script(
    'xxxecommerce1', 
    'the_ajax_script', 
    array( 'ajaxurl' => plugins_url( '/xxxecommerce.ajax.php', __FILE__ ) ) 
    );
```

This is what on my `script.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('.xxx-ecommerce-prod-opt').click(function() {

        var data = {
            action: 'test_response',
            post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
        };

        jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });

    });
});
```

this is what on my `xxxecommerce.ajax.php`

```
$x = new xxxecommerceAjax();
$x->getEmail();

class xxxecommerceAjax extends WP_Widget 
{
    function getEmail() {
        $email = get_option('xxx-ecommerce-admin2-email');
        echo $email;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call ajax like this, you have to call admin-ajax.php file through ajax url, and define a action take a look on this example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'admin-ajax.php', 
    type: 'post', 
    data: {action: 'my_action'}, 
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Notice that, i defined a action to send a request to admin-ajax.php file. Now in wordpress there are two built-in hooks to handle your ajax request that is

1. wp_ajax_YOUR_AJAX_ACTION - wp_ajax_my_action
2. wp_ajax_nopriv_YOUR_AJAX_ACTION - wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action

and you can call it like this:

```
// Call it in your themes functions.php file or in your plugin
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
    // Access more data through ajax request
    // any php method here to send the response

    // include your xxxecommerce.ajax.php file here and send response

    die();
}
```

Take a look on this example that will help you more [AJAX IN PLUGIN](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and do little more research on `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_`.

Hope this help you ;)
HAPPY NEW YEAR..

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a big help.